# Sample Hadoop Config for 4GB server?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am currently trying to set up a small Hadoop demo system on a virtual server with only 4GB of RAM. I know, 4GB is not very much for Hadoop - but that's all I have at the moment.
The server should run HDFS, YARN and Spark (on Yarn) plus a few other things not related to Hadoop.
So my idea was to reserve 2GB for the OS and the other stuff which then leaves 2GB for the Hadoop processes.
Unfortunately I am struggling a little with finding a proper configuration for this scenario.
What I have so far is:
In mapred-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>512</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
    <value>512</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx400m</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx400m</value>
</property>
```

And in yarn-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx400m</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>256</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>2048</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
    <value>512</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx400m</value>
</property>
```

Now I created a very basic Spark application and in there also giving the following parameters:

- spark.executor.memory: 512m
- spark.cores.max: 1
- spark.driver.memory: 512m
- spark.executor.instances: 1
- spark.executor.cores: 1

When executing this script with option `--master yarn-client` everything works fine; but when executing with `--master yarn-cluster` the job runs forever. In the log of the Yarn job I can read this:

> Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

To me this somehow sounds like there are not sufficient resources available!?

Now my questions:

1. Do you have some sample configuration for a 4GB Hadoop server?
2. Which configuration do I need to change to get my Spark job running with `--master yarn-cluster`?

Thank you very much and best regards!

Comment: spark version?? your configs looks ok to me

Comment: I am using the latest version, which is 1.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just have 4GB run spark in standalone local mode (local[4] or local[1]). you'd get much better results. if you're running the whole hadoop ecosystem (YARN, datanode, YARN node manager, Zookeeper etc.) - how do you expect to have any resources left for Spark?

Comment: what surprises me is that it is working in yarn-client mode and not yarn cluster mode.

Comment: in yarn-client mode the spark driver isn't running in yarn and in yarn-cluster you ask yarn  to allocate resources for the executor(s) and the driver

Comment: I know. on single node setup, in yarn client mode you need executor, driver and AM but in yarn cluster mode only AM(driver runs inside AM) and executor. So it needs less resources

Comment: I increased yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb and yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb to 3072 - and now it's working. But I will also keep the idea in mind to run it in standalone local mode. Thanks for the hints!